# Replace only certain characters in text files with printed hex format

Tags: regex, string, search, replace, translation

I'm trying to translate my old PortaPuTTY config files to the config file format of KiTTY.

PortaPutty uses a 'Field=Value' format, and KiTTY uses 'Field\Value\' format.

I can translate from PortaPuTTY to KiTTY format with:

sed -i -e 's/=/\/g' -e 's/.$/\/'

so

```
LogFileName=putty.log
LogType=0
...
```

gets translated to:

```
LogFileName\putty.log\ 
LogType\0\ 
...
```

etc.

However, in KiTTY format, special characters are translated to printed hex format.  For example:

```
PublicKeyFile=C:\Users\user.name\mykey.ppk
```

needs to be translated to:

```
PublicKeyFile\C%3A%5CUsers%5Cuser.name%5Cmykey.ppk\
```

It looks like the ranges of values that are expressed in printed hex instead of regular ascii are 0x20-0x2F, 0x3A-0x3F, or 0x7B-0x7F .

Is there a good way to translate this with sed, awk, python, etc?

Comment: This looks like a valid approach: https://superuser.com/questions/410398/any-simple-way-to-add-putty-settings-to-kitty

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there is no translation of special characters to hex-codes. File names and paths are just URL encoded.

I've created a Perl script to take care of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI::Escape;

my $regex = qr/(.*?)%3D(.*)$/p;
my $file = "/some/where/conf.file";
open my $input, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
while (<$input>) {
    chomp;
    my $result = uri_escape( $_ ) =~ s/$regex/$1\\$2\\/rg;
    print $result . "\n";
}
close $input or die "can't close $file: $!";
```

Input:

```
PublicKeyFile=C:\Users\user.name\mykey.ppk
LogFileName=putty.log
LogType=0
```

Output:

```
PublicKeyFile\C%3A%5CUsers%5Cuser.name%5Cmykey.ppk\
LogFileName\putty.log\
LogType\0\
```